# palimpsest not opening the disk management

Tags: ubuntu, disk-utility

I am using Ubuntu. I found from [web search](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-start-gnome-disk-utility-from-a-terminal-as-root-787720/) that to open Disk management below command is needed:

```
sudo palimpsest
```

But when I am trying it in the terminal and result was : `command not found`.

I also tried `gksudo` and `gksu` commands but nothing happens, help me to solve it . Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I have seen `gnome-disk-utility` details in the aptitude and Its mentioned there as `palimpsest` is from GDU .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has been renamed to `gnome-disks` in GNOME 3.6.

Execute this command:

```
apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

If you get the result "`gnome-disk-utility is already the newest version`", then run:

```
gnome-disks
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not installed.
Try to install the `gnome-disk-utility` package and see if it works.

Comment: its already installed

Comment: You get errors also if you run it without `sudo`?

Comment: yes I am getting the error.